# Pickit 2 debugger

Tags: pic

I'm new to PIC. I'm using MPLAB IDE ver 8.92 with Pickit 2 and XC8 compiler. I trying to program a PIC12F508 chip to make an LED flash. The program was built and programmed into the chip. But the LED doesn't flash, so I thought of debugging the program. I select the programmer to none, and select the debugger to Pickit 2. After there, I clicked connect, and then clicked Program. An error prompt me `PK2Error0027:  Failed verify (Address = 0x4 - Expected Value 0x64 - Value Read 0x60)`. If I clicked Run under Debugger menu, it show me `PK2Error0028: unable to enter debug mode`. Am I missing something or doing something wrong?

updated program:

```
#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000
#include <xc.h>

//__CONFIG(MCLRE_ON & CP_OFF & WDT_OFF & OSC_IntRC);

#pragma config OSC = IntRC      // Oscillator Selection bits (internal RC oscillator)
#pragma config WDT = OFF        // Watchdog Timer Enable bit (WDT disabled)
#pragma config CP = OFF         // Code Protection bit (Code protection off)
#pragma config MCLRE = ON      // GP3/MCLR Pin Function Select bit (GP3/MCLR pin function is digital input, MCLR internally tied to VDD)

void main()
{
    TRIS = 0b011111;

    GPIObits.GP5 = 1;
    __delay_ms(1000);
    GPIObits.GP5 = 0;
    __delay_ms(1000);

}
```

Include:

My circuit
[image]

Comment: To debug the PIC12F508 the AC162059 debug header is required. Do you have one of these?

Comment: You are right. Look like I need to invest one.

Comment: VSS should connect direct to the debugger. Not with a capacitor!

Comment: Removed the capacitor. I think I found the root of the problem but I don't get it. I removed the while loop, and repeat 3 times of On and Off LED codes, the LED can flash now. I don't get it why the LED is flashing non stop without my loop statement.

Comment: You need a pull up on MCLR or activate the internal Reset

Comment: Updated program. Set MCLR to 'ON' or pull MCLR pin to 12v aren't working.

Comment: 5V max on MCLR!!!!! If you put 12V on zhe chip its broken. Have a look at the datasheet. Maybe start with a development board. There are some really nice boards from microchip

Comment: Just to be sure. You have VSS connected to GND? And switched on your power supply?

Comment: Found the problem. Somehow, I cannot use while(1); to prevent MCU infinite reset, the whole MCU will stuck and LED coding will not run. I need insert a delay inside the while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the debug is that the 12F508 does not have the debug functionality.  You can only program this device.  Many of the older PICmicrocontrollers (especially the 8 pin devices) do not have debugging silicon present.  Sometimes there is a special debug header that has a debug variant of the silicon with the debug function and additional pins to access the debugger.

For more information on this topic, take a look at this post: https://www.microforum.cc/topic/16-debugging-low-pincount-picmicrocontrollers

Answer (score 0):

You need a second delay:

```
include <xc.h>
#define _XTAL_FREQ 4000000

void main()
{
    TRIS = 0b000000;

    for (;;)
    {
        GPIO = 0b00111111;    //work with 8 Bits here
        __delay_ms(1000);
        GPIO = 0b00000000;
       __delay_ms(1000);     //delay loop for OFF time
    }    
}
```

Thats the error with your LED. For the PICKit error have a look at the configuration settings. Try it with `__CONFIG _DEBUG_OFF`.

Comment: Strange I put in the 2nd delay. The LED still not flashing.

Comment: double check your configuration Bits. Is the oszillator running?

Comment: The programming with the PICKit works fine without error?

Comment: Have a look at https://alselectro.wordpress.com/2015/01/01/pic-tutorials-2-blink-an-led/ - there is a lot more setup than just setting TRIS.

Comment: Thanks for the cup. I updated the configuration still couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Please show your complete configuration. Have you tried to work with the simulator? At least this should work.